# Ram compatibility .. DIMM?

Tags: upgrade, memory

i want to increase RAM ..i will buy 512 ram ..with ddr 400

what more spec i need to match before i buy .

like i dont know whats DIMM ..and where to check number of  pin the ram has ..

---

My computer config:

MB: 775i45gv
Intel cel 2.66

Ram

Transcend JETRAM 512 MB DDR 400
DIMM 2.5-3-3

---

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to go to [Cruical.com](http://www.crucial.com/index.aspx), it has a System Scanner tool that will scan your system and will tell you exactly what type of RAM you need.
 You can then shop around for that type of RAM and find the cheapest (or closest to your location).